# Stop using location with Google Map fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I use GM fragment in my activity. And I use checkbox to show or hide that map fragment. I want deactivate GoogleMap when it is hidden to disable using GPS. But I cant do that in my activity until it is closed. Any suggestions?

```
mapGoogle = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_google)).getMap();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setMyLocationEnabled(boolean enabled)](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMyLocationEnabled%28boolean%29) to enable or disable the GPS in GoogleMap.

Run

`mapGoogle.setMyLocationEnabled(false);`

when you want to disable the GPS, and then

`mapGoogle.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

when you want to enable it again.

Comment: If you mean `setMyLocationEnabled` then possibly you are right. When I set it to `false` geolocation seems switch off. But I'm still not sure.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant setMyLocationEnabled. I updated the answer now.

Comment: for me, even if I set it to false, I still see the GPS icon on the status bar. Any other idea?

Comment: mapGoogle.setMyLocationEnabled(false);  works.... it takes some for the "GPS icon" to actually disappear from the phone's status bar. It depends on the phone.